# Sharing a Google Spreadsheet but making some information private

Tags: google-sheets

I book reservations for a sports team and need to be able to communicate with other parts of the arena what hospitality areas are booked/available. In the past there have been multiple e-mails, reports and spreadsheets which have made everyone's jobs harder. We used a Google Doc last year for the majority of the departments, which worked well, BUT we can not share customer contact information with their sales department for obvious reasons.

Is there a way to either block certain information from view or to have the mastersheet fill into another spreadsheet which can block certain cells or information?

This is an [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjHPf22sMiUydFBWQkMtVmRuelBOV1lSYjBRdklXRWc#gid=0) of the information from the mastersheet.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Google spreadsheet function `ImportRange=` will solve your problem. It will import cells from one spreadsheet to another. Then you can share only the spreadsheet you want with the sales department.

Here is [Google's function list](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en).

Alternatively, if you just need to accept data from a group/individual but not show them anything in return, you can make a form in Google Drive. The form can be sent out and when the recipient fills it out you get the results as a spreadsheet.